# How is 444141 opinion-based?

Tags: discussion

My question [Why are some emoji B&W and others too big?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444141/why-are-some-emoji-bw-and-others-too-big) has been closed as opinion-based. I don't understand the reasoning. This question asks what technical issue is leading to a reproducible visual glitch. The comments and answer address that question, and provide a practical workaround.

I don't think the question and answer were brilliantly worded, so I'm keen to clean them up anyway. Can someone point out the opinion-based or opinion-begging parts so I can address them specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing it as too broad would likely been less confusing, but the closure still seemed fit based on the level of detail available in the question.

- You mention some of the icons are appearing gray but in looking over the question multiple times it doesn't jump out which icons.
- A comment was left but it was unclear if you had attempted to address it with either an update or a reply.

With respect to the answer, it seems fine, I hadn't realized that this question had this answer when I reviewed it on the merits of the question to close it, therefore I'll reopen it.